# Connect to database from local network

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I share two computer with local network

- computer1 : Windows XP, ip = 192.168.0.1
- computer2 : Windows 7 , ip = 192.168.0.2

Now I want to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database that exists on `computer1` from `copmuter 2`  with a win app

I use below connection string and check `Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections` but I get an error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified*

Connection string:

```
Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True
```

and

```
Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=false
```

Comment: does computer1 have named or default SQL server instance ?

Comment: computer1 have default SQL server instance

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says, it could be a network-related error.
Does your server really have the IP 192.168.0.1?
Does it accept incoming connections?
Do you run a firewall such as the windows firewall that blocks incoming connections?

It could also be that you have not configured your sql server to accept remote connections, but only connections from localhost.

Comment: my comuter's 1 ip is 192.168.0.1 - i check firewall - i check remote connections

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=false
```

Here you must specify the **Uid= your usernam**e and **Password=password**.
Because you are making integrated security= false

Comment: i don't have username and password

Comment: then integrated security should be equal to true

Answer (score 0):

As dontomaso pointed out, check that "Allow Remote connections" option is enabled on the server. If i recall, its disabled by default.

(cant post images directly yet, heres the link)

[Allow Remote connections option screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKBRS.png)

Comment: i check "Allow Remote connections"

Answer (score -1):

If you connect from another machine you check the configuration:

- SQL service account: NetworkService
- Ensure SQL server running the SQL Browser service
- In the Protocols:

  - Named pipes: set Enableb (to connect the computer to install SQL user name)
  - TCP / IP: Enableb set (to connect using the IP address of the machine IP_dia LAN)
          -> 2 This section Enableb all, they want to use way also.
  - Shared Momory: **DISABLED** choose, if this part is ENABLEB can not connect via LAN or Internet.

    ```
    (string strCon = "Data Source=192.168.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=sa;Password=sa";)
    ```

To connect via the Internet you here take your network IP address on the Internet.